# Select a DataFrame date index as a string

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching historical commodity prices using an API, which has a 10k row limit each call. The Python package for that API has startDate and endDate parameters. The data is fed starting from the endDate. The index in a resulting df is the date.

Instead of looking at where the API stopped sending data manually, I thought of deleting the last date, where only certain commodities were able to appear, and use that date as the endDate, making it the starting point for the next batch.

There's probably a better way of achieving what I want, but my question for now is how do I get the index of a df as a string?

Example output:

```
df = fetchData(initDate='1975-01-01', output_type='df')
```

```
            symbol  open      high       low        close
2021-08-09  AU      4.16      4.18       4.04       4.05
2021-08-09  CU      34685     34685      34685      34685
2021-08-09  PT      67.88     67.90      65.15      65.93
...
2018-05-16  AL      3.16      3.18       3.04       3.05
2018-05-16  CO      5         5.1        4.9        5.3
2018-05-15  AU      3.88      3.90       3.15       3.93
```

In this case, I want to get '2018-05-15', delete the lines with that date, put it into a variable and add it to the endDate parameter like such:

```
df = fetchData( initDate='1975-01-01', endDate='2018-08-15', output_type='df')
```

The closest I've gotten is with this:

```
df.iloc[-1,0]
```

Which as expected outputs the symbol AU. How to I get it to output the index?

Alternatively, would there be a better way to 'append' the data in every call without creating duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the last index as a string with this

```
date= list(df.index)
print(date[-1])
```

output:

```
2018-05-15 00:00:00
```